# How do I create a new object in javascript based on a type-string?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

How do I create a new object in javascript based on a variable type-string (containing the name of the object)?

Now I have: (with more tools coming the list will get longer...)

```
function getTool(name){
  switch(name){
    case "SelectTool":
      return new SelectTool();
      break;
    case "LineTool":
      return new LineTool();
      break;
    case "BlurTool":
      return new BlurTool();
      break;
    case "PointerTool":
    default:
      return new PointerTool();
      break;
  }
}
```

And defined my tools like:

```
PointerTool.prototype = new Tool;
PointerTool.prototype.constructor = PointerTool;
function PointerTool(){
  this.name = "PointerTool";
}
PointerTool.prototype.click = function(x, y){
  info("You clicked at: "+x+", "+y);
}
```

I would like to get ride of the (growing) switch statement, it seems 'wrong'.

Comment: Hypothetically, eval could do it ...

Comment: @Šime Vidas, but practically, eval should be avoided at all costs :D

Comment: @Gabi, I agree that `eval()` is not the correct solution here, but I'm curious why you assert that "eval should be avoided at all costs". It is a non-deprecated feature of the language, with appropriate (and inappropriate) uses -- just like every other feature.

Comment: @Šime: I'll ask Jeff to add downvotes on comments! :-P

Comment: @Lee I didn't say that. Gabi said it.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: in this case eval usage is proper. However i'd create Tools object and do `if (str_tool in Tools) obj_tool = new Tools[str_tool]`

Comment: @Lee But from what I understand, using eval restricts minifiers from shortening variable names. So it's actually valid to say "never use eval".

Comment: @Lee I consider myself clumsy enough to make a stupid mistake using dangerous tools, so I avoid it at all costs.

Comment: @Gabi: Fair enough.  All effective coders set "personal rules to code by"... I have many of my own.

Comment: Sometimes `eval` is the only answer, and that is when it should be used. If these objects were defined within an anonymous self executing function, they could not be referenced using `window[constructor]`.

Comment: Whoa! Did my question just become a little `ev<strike>i</strike>al` flame-war :)

Comment: @MooGoo: in that case, I would define an object within the namespace of that self-invoking anonymous function with the functions I want to call this way as properties of that object. Then you can still use `someObject[functionName]`.

Comment: There's Always Another Way of course. Nearly any code can be written in a way to avoid eval. However eval can often make working with *existing* code so much easier without the need to refactor. It is not soooo eeeevvvilll that you should rewrite half of your crap code just to avoid it, so long as you keep in mind the "better" way to do things in the future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function getTool(name){
  return ( typeof window[name] === 'function' ) ? 
                                    new window[name]() : {/*some default*/};
}
```

Assumes `PointerTool` constructor is defined in the global `window` namespace. Replace that with whatever namespace you're using.

Comment: If you're using Node.js you can use the GLOBAL object to do this same thing.

Comment: I'll go with this solution for now, totaly forgot that _everything_ is a function, thus also the global `window` object/functions/namespace :)

Comment: @Dribbel - Sounds good. I only used `window` because I wasn't certain of the namespace. I'd recommend defining them in some other namespace if you are using `window`. The same technique can be used, but if `getTool` isn't doing anything else, you could eliminate that function call.

Answer (score 8):

You should consider rethinking your approach. It would be better to have something like a `Tools` object, which would have the tools as properties, like

```
Tools = {"SelectTool": SelectTool /* etc */}`.
```

This way, you could access the tools both as `new Tools.SelectTool` and `new Tools[var_with_tool_name]`.

Comment: Yes, but it works even if the tools are in different namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you're declaring `PointerTool` as a function in the global scope.  Assuming your javascript is running the browser, the "global scope" is *actually* the same as the `window` object.  That means that if you have a constructor:

```
function PointerTool() {
   ...
}
```

that's the same as this:

```
window.PointerTool = function() {
   ...
}
```

So now, in your getTool function, you can access your constructor functions like this:

```
function getTool(name){
    return new window[name]();
}
```

---

A more "future proof" way to do this would be to do define your own namespace object, in which you'll place all your various tool constructors.  Something like this ("myproject" would be the short name of your project or system):

```
var myproject = { tools: {} };

// Pointer Tool Constructor
myproject.tools.PointerTool = function() {
   ...
}

// Line Tool Constructor
myproject.tools.LineTool = function() {
   ...
}

// and so on
```

Then your getTool function would look like this:

```
function getTool(name){
    return new myproject.tools[name]();
}
```

This approach keeps your stuff isolated from whatever other stuff happens to be defined in the global/window scope.

Comment: No, `function PointerTool` ≠ `window.PointerTool = function`: the first is a function *declaration*, the second a function *expression*. http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl

Comment: True, but in the context of this question, it is equal enough. That is, you can reference `PointerTool` by using `window.PointerTool`, which is the point of this answer.