# Generate JavaScript Classes from JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file has information and data about my work like this :

```
{
"Employes":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fullName": "Test Test"
        }
    ],
"Infos":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "Test Test test test test",
            "employes": 1
        }
  ]
}
```

I want to generate `Employes` and `Infos` Classes automatically on JS code and the add some method to it.

fetchJSONFile it's a function to get Data from JSON file using AJAX:

```
function fetchJSONFile(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'datas.json');
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

So, here on generate function I want to generate Classes automaticaly and assign object to it, I try by doing this:

```
function generate(nameOfObject){
        fetchJSONFile(function(data){
            employes = Object.assign(new Employes(), ...data[nameOfObject]);
            console.log(employes);
        });
    }
```

On this line I assign JSON object to My `Employes()` classes, my question is how to generate `Employes()` automatically assign of JSON Type, so if is `Infos` for example new `Employes()` become new `Infos()` ... etc.

I want to do that, to add some functions to those Classes, like `addNew()`, `deleteOne()` .... etc, All about CRUD.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: I think this may have been discussed here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360680/how-do-i-create-a-new-object-in-javascript-based-on-a-type-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `DynamicClass` class which accepts an input value and `type` which could be `Employes, Infos...`

```
function DynamicClass (data, type) {
  this.type = type;
  // Init function
}
DynamicClass.prototype.xxxx = function () {}
```

You can now just use your data object to create the classes.

```
fetchJSONFile(function(data){
  for(var key in data) {
    var classObj  = new DynamicClass(data[key], key);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the object returned has only 2 keys you could `map` through the entries and create 2 array variables like this:

If you have more then 2 properties, then you can use a `switch` inside the inner `map`:

```js
function Employee() { this.defaultEmployeeProp = "default" }
function Infos() { this.defaultInfosProp = "default" }

const data={"Employes":[{"id":1,"fullName":"Test Test"}],"Infos":[{"id":1,"address":"Test Test test test test","employes":1}]}

const [employees, infos] = Object.entries(data).map(([key, values]) =>
  values.map(e => Object.assign(key === "Employes" ? new Employee() : new Infos(), e))
)

console.log(employees)
console.log(infos)
```

If you want all types of objects to have the same `prototype`, then there is no need for a ternary inside the `map`. Create a generic constructor function or a `class`, then create instances of the `class`. If you want specific behavior for each type of object, you can always `extend` the class and use the `switch` as mentioned in the previous snippet

```js
function GenericConstructor() {
  this.default = "default"
}

GenericConstructor.prototype.commonMethod = function() {
  console.log("common method called")
}

const data={"Employes":[{"id":1,"fullName":"Test Test"}],"Infos":[{"id":1,"address":"Test Test test test test","employes":1}]}

const [employees, infos] = Object.entries(data).map(([key, values]) =>
  values.map(e => Object.assign(new GenericConstructor(), e))
)

console.log(employees)
console.log(infos)
```

Comment: The problem here sir, is if I add new type on JSON file, I need to create the Classe manually. I want to generate classes automatically

Comment: Does the class of all the types have the same `prototypes`? @sayou

Comment: @varunagarwal, on this moment all those classes has the same methods, (just CRUD)

Comment: @sayou If all the items have the same behavior, create a generic class and then `Object.assign(new GenericClass(), e)`?

Comment: @adiga can you please give an example how to use it ?

Comment: @sayou added another snippet to the asnwer